# Obtain results from a query

Tags: sql

I have a table with a lot of data, from a query I could obtain values that I was looking but on the table when I made a query I obtained a general count

```
    SELECT (CODISTRITO + CODMANZANA+CODLOTE)AS CODMAN,
    (SELECT count(TYPE) from dbo.test WHERE TYPE  = 'ABC')  as ABC,
    (SELECT count(TYPE ) from dbo.test WHERE TYPE = 'DEF')  as DEF,
    (SELECT count(TYPE ) from dbo.test WHERE TYPE = 'GHI')  as GHI,
    (SELECT count(TYPE ) from dbo.test WHERE TYPE = 'JKL')  as JKL
FROM dbo.test

CODEMAN    ABC   DEF   GHI   JKL   
1234567    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234578    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234579    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234510    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234511    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234512    1000  4000  6000  8000
1234513    1000  4000  6000  8000
```

I would like to have a table where I can see the individual quantity for ABC,DEF,GHI, JKL (something like this):

```
CODEMAN    ABC   DEF   GHI   JKL   
1234567    200  1000  1000  1000
1234578    100  500   1000  2000
1234579    300  500   2000  1000
1234510    50   700   500   1000
1234511    150  300   500   1000
1234512    200  500   500   1000
1234513    100  500   500    0
```

If your sum each value in ABC is = 1000, etc (So is a general count) as I have in my first table

Comment: Can you should us what your table looks like?

Comment: You are looking to PIVOT the count of each type, what database are you using?  You should search for pivot+your database and you'll find a lot of questions that have been answered.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll need to employ a SUM() for each TYPE you want a special count for. Check this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447397/multiple-counts-and-a-group-by/13447411#13447411

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Keeping your DBMS a secret makes this question unclear and not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CODISTRITO + CODMANZANA + CODLOTE AS CODMAN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE  = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABC,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE  = 'DEF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DEF,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE  = 'GHI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GHI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE  = 'JKL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JKL
FROM dbo.test
GROUP BY CODISTRITO, CODMANZANA, CODLOTE
```